Why pairs cannot mix types in NFU?
I am reading Randall Holmes’s Elementary Set Theory with a Universal Set and I don’t understand the following part, in chapter 9, about the would-be function that sends each element of a set to its equivalence class:

A caution: in a stratified set definition, $[x]$ is not at the same “type” as
$x$. As a result, the relation between $x$ and $[x]$ does not necessarily exist.

I would understand if Kuratowski pairs were used: the $\{x,y\}$ in $(x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ forces $x$ and $y$ to have the same type. However, in the book, “primitive pairs” are used (provided by an axiom) and as such, I don’t get why $x \mapsto [x]$ could not be defined by stratified comprehension like this (the types are shown as exponents):
$$\left\{ p \; \middle| \; \exists x^0, \; \exists C^1, \; p^0 = \left( x^0, C^1 \right)^0 \; \wedge \; C^1 = \left[ x^0 \right]^1 \right\} . $$
This definition seems valid to me because the type of a pair is not constrained as far as I understand, and any two elements can make a pair, whatever their type.
What am I missing?

Randall's definition of stratified sentence (on p. 44) requires that a pair in a stratified sentence has the same type as either of its elements.

@RobArthan I guess you are talking about this part: “In each atomic sentence $x = y$, $x ; \pi_1 ; y$, $x ; \pi_2 ; y$ in $\varphi$, the ‘types’ of
the variables $x$ and $y$ are the same.” But $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ do not appear in my formula, and thus I do not get how it is unstratified.

I agree that there does seem to be a problem. I was expecting Randall to have used $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ in the definition of equality of a variable with a pair, but he doesn't. I will muse on it.
